# How can I optimize my simple code (python)?

Tags: python, arrays, random

I'm taking an intro programming class and am working ahead on some assignments that aren't due for a few weeks.  This one asks me to take three text files - names, titles, and descriptions - and use them to randomly generate "fantasy character" names.  My code runs and does what I want it to, but I feel like it's cluttered and could be cleaned up quite a bit.  Keep in mind that this is an INTRO course and in class have just covered basic boolean logic, loops, arrays, etc.; not classes, object-oriented, or any advanced stuff (I'm trying to learn some of this on my own).

```
import random
def main():
    for i in range(10):        
        # Load names, titles, descriptions into arrays
        names = loadFile('names.txt')
        title = loadFile('titles.txt')
        descriptor = loadFile('descriptors.txt')
        # Generate random number based on list length
        nameListLength = len(names)
        titleListLength = len(title)
        descListLength = len(descriptor)
        firstNameIndex = random.randrange(nameListLength)
        lastNameIndex = random.randrange(nameListLength)
        randTitleIndex = random.randrange(titleListLength)
        randDescriptor = random.randrange(descListLength)
        # Choose random list entry
        firstName = names[firstNameIndex]
        lastName = names[lastNameIndex]
        title2 = title[randTitleIndex]
        description = descriptor[randDescriptor]
        nameList = [title2, firstName, lastName, description]
        dumpFile(nameList)
        print(title2, firstName, lastName, 'the', description)
    print()
    print('These names have been written to \"CharacterNames.txt\".')

def dumpFile(nameList):
    title = str(nameList[0])
    firstName = str(nameList[1])
    lastName = str(nameList[2])
    descriptor = str(nameList[3])
    outfile = open('CharacterNames.txt', 'a')
    outfile.write(title + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' ' +
                  'the' + ' ' + descriptor + '\n')
    outfile.write('\n')
    outfile.close()

def loadFile(nameFile):   
    nameList = open(nameFile, 'r')
    nameArray = []
    for line in nameList:       
        name = line
        name = name.rstrip('\n')
        nameArray.append(name)
    nameList.close()
    return nameArray   

main()
```

Comment: You might get more people interested in checking it over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Too Broad as there is no specific problem or question. For improvements to working code you should try the Code Review site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to CodeReview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see value in having others look at your code and rewrite it as they would do it. I kind of ignored your restriction on "any advanced stuff," although I don't think any of it will be too complicated for you to intuit. Here's my rewrite:

```
import random

def generatePerson(names=loadFile('names.txt'),
                   titles=loadFile('titles.txt'),
                   descriptons=loadFile('descriptors.txt')):
    firstName = random.choice(names)
    lastName = random.choice(names)
    title = random.choice(titles)
    description = random.choice(descriptons)
    return '{} {} {} the {}'.format(title, firstName, lastName, description)

def main():
    people = [generatePerson() for _ in range(10)]
    dumpFile('\n\n'.join(people))
    print('\n'.join(people))
    print('\nThese names have been written to "CharacterNames.txt".')

def dumpFile(data, filename='CharacterNames.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)

def loadFile(nameFile):
    with open(nameFile, 'r') as nameList:
        return nameList.read().splitlines()

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It still resembles your code in many ways, however, most of it has been rewritten. Now for details on some of the more drastic changes.

1. I moved the code related to picking random strings from the three lists into its own function `generatePerson`. This makes the easier to maintain in case the method of generating a random person or something else changes in the future.
2. I greatly simplified the logic of picking the random strings by using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).
3. I used a trick that uses default arguments in `generatePerson` to avoid reading from the three files each time a random name is created. The only part of this trick that you should know for now is that the values of default arguments are created only once in Python.
4. Instead of passing a list into `dumpFile`, I opted to pass a string, which I can then immediately write to the file. This makes more sense because I had `generatePerson` return the formatted string for that person rather than `[title, firstName, lastName, description]`.
5. This is mostly just my preference, but I don't really like for-loops, so in `main` I used a list comprehension to create a list of 10 random names. From there, I used [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to create a single string with all ten names that is suitable to be passed to `dumpFile` and `print`.

I believe that is (nearly) all of the changes I made. If I missed something or if you need further clarification on anything I mentioned either comment on my answer or just [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Move file operations before the 'for' loop - there is no need to re-read the files 10 times. That should make the application run much faster.